# Hibernate Second Level Caching inverse collection

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to second level cache an inverse collection?
Whenever I add objects to the other end (and also to the inverse end, although not really sure what the point is as its not persisted), the version doesnt change on the inverse end and hibernate rereads the old collection from the cache the next time I ask for it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Dwayne

Comment: Did you try to fix your mapping or your bidirectional association as I suggested in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951350/hibernate-bi-directional-manytomany-updates-with-second-level-cache.