# Hibernate issue: @OneToMany annotation returns duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am facing a problem with Hibernate (4.3.0) where as unidirectional @OneToMany returns duplicates.

My database structure (MySQL with InnoDB) where as 'entry' table has a 1:N relationship with 'entry_address' table. The 'entry' table is the main table and 'entry_address' is a sub-table of 'entry' table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `modifiedTS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdTS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `entry` (`id`, `name`, `active`, `modifiedTS`, `createdTS`) VALUES
(1, 'Test1', 0, '2012-11-05 13:41:03', '2012-11-01 10:11:22'),
(2, 'Test2', 1, '2012-11-05 11:19:37', '2012-11-01 10:11:33'),
(3, 'Test3', 1, '2012-11-05 11:19:37', '2012-11-01 10:11:44');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry_address` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `precedence` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `line` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `entry_address_uq` (`id`,`precedence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `entry_address` (`id`, `precedence`, `line`, `line2`, `street`, `street2`, `zip`, `city`, `country`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Line4.1', 'Line4.2', 'Street4.1', 'Street4.2', 9488, 'Schellenberg', 'Liechtenstein'),
(2, 10, 'Line1.1', 'Line1.2', 'Street1.1', 'Street1.2', 9492, 'Eschen', 'Liechtenstein'),
(2, 20, 'Line2.1', 'Line2.2', 'Street2.1', 'Street2.2', 9490, 'Vaduz', 'Liechtenstein'),
(2, 30, 'Line3.1', 'Line3.2', 'Street3.1', 'Street3.2', 9494, 'Schaan', 'Liechtenstein'),
(3, 10, 'Line5.1', 'Line5.2', 'Street5.1', 'Street5.2', 9492, 'Eschen', 'Liechtenstein'),
(3, 20, 'Line6.1', 'Line6.2', 'Street6.1', 'Street6.2', 9492, 'Eschen', 'Liechtenstein');

ALTER TABLE `entry_address`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `entry_address_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `entry` (`id`);
```

Here's the minimal code of "entry" entity.

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "entry")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Collection<EntryAddress> addresses;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Entry [id=%s, name=%s, addresses=%s]", id, name, addresses);
    }
}
```

Here's the minimal code of "entry_address" entity:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "entry_address")
public class EntryAddress {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "line")
    private String line;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("EntryAddress [line=%s]", line);
    }
}
```

This is the query done by Hibernate (looks good!):
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_1_, this_.name as name0_1_, addresses2_.id as id0_3_, addresses2_.id as id1_3_, addresses2_.id as id1_0_, addresses2_.line as line1_0_ from entry this_ left outer join entry_address addresses2_ on this_.id=addresses2_.id

[image: MySQL Output]

But if I run JUnit using:

```java
import java.util.Collection;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import li.pitschmann.transaction.dao.EntryDao;
import li.pitschmann.transaction.entity.Entry;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;

@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:**/web-spring.xml"})
public class EntryDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private EntryDao entryDao;

    @Test
    public void findAllEntries() {
        Collection<Entry> entries = entryDao.findEntries();

        Assert.assertNotNull(entries);

        for (Entry e : entries) {
            System.out.println("++: " + e);
        }
        // Assert.assertEquals(3, entries.size());

    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Collection;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import li.pitschmann.transaction.dao.EntryDao;
import li.pitschmann.transaction.entity.Entry;

public class EntryDaoImpl implements EntryDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public Collection<Entry> findEntries() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Entry.class).list();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Spring XML (most important part, Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE):

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- MySQL DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entry_db" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>li.pitschmann.transaction.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The console log is:

```
++: Entry [id=1, name=Test1, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line4.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, name=Test3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1], EntryAddress [line=Line5.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, name=Test3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1], EntryAddress [line=Line5.1]]]
```

I also tried to use @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) instead of FetchType.EAGER - same issue with duplicate addresses.

```
++: Entry [id=1, name=Test1, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line4.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, name=Test3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1], EntryAddress [line=Line5.1]]]
```

**Expectation**

This is my expecation (3 entry objects with different addresses):

```
++: Entry [id=1, name=Test1, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line4.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line2.1], EntryAddress [line=Line3.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, name=Test3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1], EntryAddress [line=Line6.1]]]
```

Is there a bug in Hibernate or am I doing something wrong? Hope someone can help me to find the root cause?! Thank you :-)

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.0? Do you have a time machine?

Comment: Wrong version! The version of Hibernate ORM is 4.1.8.FINAL. Version 4.3.0 belongs to Hibernate Validatory. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to modify your method like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public Collection<Entry> findEntries() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
      .createCriteria(Entry.class)
      .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
      .list();
}
```

Also, change `addresses` to a `Set`:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Set<EntryAddress> addresses;
```

Edit:

Oh...In `EntryAddress` you have `id` defined as the `@Id` but it is not unique. You should make `id` the primary key and have it auto increment like you do in `Entry`. Then create another field in `EntryAddress` that is the foreign key to `Entry` called something like `entry_id`.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggested method is solving one part (duplicated entry objects):
++: Entry [id=1, name=Test1, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line4.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, name=Test2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1], EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, name=Test3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1], EntryAddress [line=Line5.1]]]

But address duplicates still persists :-(

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also tried with Set but returns only one address and more addresses. For example: Entry 2 should contain 3 addresses, Entry 3 should contain 2 addresses.
++: Entry [id=1, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line4.1]]]
++: Entry [id=2, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line1.1]]]
++: Entry [id=3, addresses=[EntryAddress [line=Line5.1]]]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your hint to add entry_id and make id as primary key solved the issue.

Comment: I thought @Id already made it a primary key with a uniques constraint?

Comment: Switching from List to Set saved my life.

Comment: This also works for `@ManyToMany`.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice point regarding @Id within EntryAddress attached to one of the Foreign Keys. It's a typical false fix of "Persistent entity 'MyEntity' should have primary key" error.