# Create a rule to not repeat the attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Could you give me an idea of ​​how to do this: the creation of a rule, that when saving a city, the system does not accept two cities with the same name for the same state?

I'm using spring boot ...

My Cidade entity :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Cidade SET ativo = 0 WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "ativo = 1")
public class Cidade extends BaseEntity {

private String nome;
private String sigla;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Estado estado;

private Double populacao;

}
```

My Cidade Resource:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/api/cidade") 
public class CidadeResource {
        
    @Autowired
    private CidadeRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private EstadoRepository repositoryEstado;
    @Autowired
    private CidadeResourceMapper mapper;

    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<PageDto<CidadeDTO>> getPageWithQuery(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Cidade.class ) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageble) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(convertToPageDto(predicate, pageble));
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CidadeDTO> add(@Valid @RequestBody CidadeWriteDTO dto) throws Exception {
        Cidade entity = this.mapper.fromDto(dto);
        
        entity = repository.save(entity);
        
        ResponseEntity<CidadeDTO> re = ResponseEntity.ok(this.convertToDto(entity));
        
        return re;
                
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CidadeDTO> get(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(convertToDto(repository.findById(id).get()));
    }
        
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CidadeDTO> update(@Valid @RequestBody CidadeWriteDTO dto, @PathVariable Integer id) throws AppException {
        
        Optional<Cidade> entity = repository.findById(id);
        if (entity.isPresent()) {
                        
            Double qtdPopulacao = 0D;
            if (entity.get().getEstado().getPopulacao() == null)
                qtdPopulacao = entity.get().getPopulacao();
            else {
                // Remove a população da cidade (antes da alteração)
                qtdPopulacao = entity.get().getEstado().getPopulacao() - entity.get().getPopulacao();
            }
            
            this.mapper.merge(entity.get(), dto);

            // Adiciona a população da cidade
            qtdPopulacao += dto.getPopulacao();
            
            // Atualiza os dados no estado
            entity.get().getEstado().setPopulacao(qtdPopulacao);
            
            // Salva a entidade no BD
            repositoryEstado.save(entity.get().getEstado());
            
            if (dto.getPopulacao() < 0)
                throw new AppException("Valor inválido da quantidade da população");

            
            Cidade mergedEntity = repository.save(entity.get());
            
            ResponseEntity<CidadeDTO> re = ResponseEntity.ok(this.convertToDto(mergedEntity));
            
            return re;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        
    }   

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {
        
        repository.deleteById(id);
        
    }
    
    private PageDto<CidadeDTO> convertToPageDto(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageble) {
        Page<Cidade> pageEntity = repository.findAll(predicate, pageble);
        
        return new PageDto<>(StreamSupport.stream(pageEntity.spliterator(), false).map(this::convertToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), pageEntity.getTotalElements());
    }      
    
    private CidadeDTO convertToDto(Cidade entity) {
        return mapper.toDto(entity);
    }
        
}
```

Where would I create the rule to avoid duplicating the city in the database? I just want there to be only one city for a state when the user searches ...

Comment: could you please add existing code, It would be better to answer.

Comment: Oh @Sri I COMPLETED IT... =)

Comment: Can you use  @Column(unique = true) for the city and try

Comment: @Sri What class do I test this in?

Comment: Please add the code of other entity class ie Estado, There should to proper mapping with please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256569/hibernate-issue-onetomany-annotation-returns-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the [help](https://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-criar-uma-regra-para-nao-ter-repeticao-do-atributo/412100/4):

```
    ALTER TABLE cidade
    ADD CONSTRAINT uk_cidade UNIQUE (estado_id, nome);
```